# Java input Letter

Tags: java

I'm doing an java activity that if Name start with letter A-G and Ends with Letter H-z the output is invalid heres my code:

```
System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
String str = in.readLine();
 if(str.startsWith("a" )){
            System.out.print("INVALID!");
        }  if(str.endsWith("h")){
            System.out.print("INVALID!");
        }
```

This works but how can i implement letter a to g and h to z 
i already try this [a-g] and it not WORK!

Comment: Why not take a stab at it. I'd look at the methods available in the String class to extract the first char. Take it from there!

Comment: +1 with @HovercraftFullOfEels. Also, you might want to consider that the user might enter both uppercase and lowercase characters. Keep that in mind when you validate.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look into [`String.startsWith()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29) and [`String.endsWith()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith%28java.lang.String%29).  Both of those String methods will be invaluable to this task.

Comment: `String.startsWith()` not beginsWith()

Comment: Good catch.  I had the link going to the right place, but the wording was not correct.

Comment: I noticed because I had to click just to check if they had added that method in JAVA 7 :)

Comment: still i cant do it can you post a sample code for this?.thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can also consider using regular expression in the [String.matches()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) method. Something like this:

```
string.matches("^[A-Ga-g].*.[H-Zh-z]") //Where string is a variable in here
```

**Note:** This regex will return whether the given string starts with A-G (in upper/lower case) and ends with H-Z (in either upper/lower case). So you might want to **negate** it while performing your validation. Something like this:

```
if(!string.matches("^[A-Ga-g].*.[H-Zh-z]")){
 //Signifies that the input does not start with A-G and ends with H-Z
}
```

Comment: I tried with String `abc` ,it should be valid but the result is invalid.  I think it should like this : `if (!str.matches("[A-Ga-g].*.[H-Zh-z]")) {}`

Comment: @wodong: you're correct. I just wanted to show how you *can detect* the existence rather than *validate*. But yes, I agree, I should've provided that as part of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: yeah regular expression is far better than other options

Comment: @*downvoter:* it would be helpful if you specify the reason behind downvoting. If there's a problem with my solution, do please leave a comment :) It's frustrating to see a downvote without an explanation as to why!

Comment: sir Sujay i tried your codes but sorry to tell when i input "Zaa" it print Invalid which this name will be valid the First Letter is started with the letter Z the last letter is A ..

Comment: @xyvyre: well, like i said in my note, this regex tests whether the given string *starts with A-G and ends with H-Z*. So all you've to do is take a `!` of it. I updated my note to show a code snippet of the same :) btw, you can just call me Sujay and not Sir Sujay....haven't got a knighthood....not yet atleast :D

Comment: @Sujay Just an opinion, but regular expressions for simple string manipulation is overkill and leads to, if not abuse, then overuse, of regular expressions in my experience (and then they all get converted to constants and stuck in a constants class or interface with no documentation as to what they do, so in order to decipher the code, now you have to decipher *two* codes!)  Apache Commons Lang's StringUtils is more than sufficient for all but the most complex tasks, and this does not fall into the category of being a complex task.

Comment: @MetroidFan2002: My intention was to provide the OP with one more option that he can consider. However, I do agree with you, regular expression can sometimes be a pain, if not properly documented. StringUtils is indeed a good suggestion, +1 for that!